# How to close document without closing its window?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I create a Mac document based project. After I load a file in a window, I want to clear the content by click the "close" menu item, and not close the window. Then I can load other document in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

You are not very specific so it is difficult to give specific advise.

In general if I were doing this I would redirect the 'Close' and 'Open' menu items in the `MainMenu.xib` file to my own custom `IBAction` methods.  These custom methods would then alter any data and operate on the window and it's views.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is counter-intuitive for the user who would expect *Close* to close the window (possibly asking if they want to save the content first).

I think you just need some sort of *Clear* action (menu item, toolbar button and key binding) which makes the feature far more obvious and will allow your App to conform to Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html).